# viewing database in android

Tags: android, database

It's about appointment.

I have 5 pages linked one after the other.

In the 4th page the data enters the database from the data given in the 3rd page by the user.

Before the user confirms the appointment date and time the user should view the database in the list view form...

This is what i have coded. Could you please help me and correct me ?

My base adapter class:

```
public class viewlistadapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
SQLiteDatabase sdb;

private Context viewcontext;
ArrayList v1=new ArrayList();
ArrayList v2=new ArrayList();
ArrayList v3=new ArrayList();
ArrayList v4=new ArrayList();
ArrayList v5=new ArrayList();

int length;

public viewlistadapter(viewlist vl, ArrayList value12, ArrayList value22, ArrayList     value32, ArrayList value42, ArrayList value52)
{
    viewcontext=vl;
    v1=value12;
    v2=value22;
    v3=value32;
    v4=value42;
    v5=value52;
    length=v1.size();

}
public viewlistadapter(viewlist vl, String value12, String value22,
        String value32, String value42, String value52) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public int getCount() 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return length;
}

public Object getItem(int arg0) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LinearLayout l=new LinearLayout(viewcontext);

    TextView tv1=new TextView(viewcontext);
    TextView tv2=new TextView(viewcontext);
    TextView tv3=new TextView(viewcontext);
    TextView tv4=new TextView(viewcontext);
    TextView tv5=new TextView(viewcontext);

    tv1.setText((String) v1.get(position));
    tv2.setText((String) v2.get(position));
    tv3.setText((String) v3.get(position));
    tv4.setText((String) v4.get(position));
    tv5.setText((String) v5.get(position));

    l.addView(tv1);
    l.addView(tv2);
    l.addView(tv3);
    l.addView(tv4);
    l.addView(tv5);

    return l;

}
}
```

and the activity class is

```
public class viewlist extends Activity 
{
TextView viewtv1;
Button viewbutt;
ListView lv;
TextView statustv;
viewlistadapter vla;
SQLiteDatabase db=null;
SQLiteDatabase sdb;
final String path="/data/data/a.b.seventeenth/databases/";
final String dbname="checking2.db";

ArrayList value12=new ArrayList();
ArrayList value22=new ArrayList();
ArrayList value32=new ArrayList();
ArrayList value42=new ArrayList();
ArrayList value52=new ArrayList();

public void createdb()
{
    try
    {
        sdb=openOrCreateDatabase("checking2.db",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,   null);


    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 5000).show();
    }

}


public void viewdb()
{
    try 
    {
        sdb=openOrCreateDatabase("checking2.db",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);        



        String res="";
        Cursor c=sdb.query("login",null, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(!c.isAfterLast())
        {
            value12.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
            value22.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
            value32.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("month")));
            value42.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("hours")));
            value52.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("minutes")));
            c.moveToNext();
            /*status=sdb.view("login", null, value12);
            return status;*/
            //long s=sdb.insertOrThrow("login", null, value12);             //long s= sdb.view("login", null, value12);
        }

        lv.setAdapter(new viewlistadapter(this,value12,value22,value32,value42,value52));


    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 500000).show();
    }

}

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listviewform);

        viewbutt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.viewbutt);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        statustv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.statustv);


        try 
        {
            sdb=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path+dbname,null ,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } 

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    /*
        try {
            if(db==null)
            {

            statustv.setText("no one has booked the appointment for today!!");

            }
            else
            {
                viewdb();

            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e1.toString(), 500000).show();
        }
    */
        //statustv.setText(text, type)
    try {
        viewbutt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {               
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try 
                {
                    Bundle b=viewlist.this.getIntent().getExtras();
                    String name=b.getString("name");
                    int date=b.getInt("date");
                    int month=b.getInt("month");
                    int hour=b.getInt("hour");
                    int minutes=b.getInt("minutes");
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),register.class);

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(date)+String.valueOf(hour)+String.valueOf(minutes), 5000).show();

                    i.putExtra("name",name);
                    /*a.putExtra("phone_no",phone_no);
                    a.putExtra("email", email);*/
                    i.putExtra("date", date);
                    i.putExtra("month", month);
                    i.putExtra("hour", hour);
                    i.putExtra("minutes", minutes);
                    i.putExtra("name", name);

                    startActivity(i);
                } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 5000).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 500000).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The question is really broad. You should narrow the scope as much as possible before posting a question.

Comment: sure i will take c are of it naext time, fiddler...can you help me out with a solution for it...please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we can try this.Program "sqlite browser" can shows a data in the database. You can download it here(http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/). It is easy to use.

2..
Open cmd  go to programme tools ...

```
D:\Android Setup\android-sdk_r17-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb
shell
# cd data
cd data
# cd data
cd data
# cd com.maid.testnews(package name )
cd com.maid.testnews
# cd databases
cd databases
# sqlite3 Maidnews(Database name )
sqlite3 Maidnews
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

sqlite> select * from maidtitle;(table name )
```

Saw your result ....

3.
In the Eclipse look at the File Explorer tab (near the Console tab). Or look at menu "Window -> Show View -> Other... -> File Explorer". Emulator should be run. In the File Explorer window go to the folder "data/data/[your_package_name]/databases/". There you can find your database. You can export it to the your computer. At the right top corner of the window there is a button "pull a file from device". Select database, click that button and save a database on the computer.

Comment: thnk u maid786 i thnk my question was not proper or you have not understood what i want....i want to view the data from the database in a listview format in the working application....